# R knitr error 41 when producing pdf (windows)

Tags: r, pdf, latex, knitr

I have been trying to make a simple PDF using the "Knit PDF" functionality from RStudio.

Every time I try to convert the sample doc to a PDF I get the following message:

> |.............                                                    |  20%
>
> ordinary text without R code
>
> |..........................                                       |  40%
>
> label: unnamed-chunk-1
>
> |.......................................                          |  60%
>
> ordinary text without R code
>
> |....................................................             |  80%
>
> label: unnamed-chunk-2 (with options)
>
> List of 1
>
> $ echo: logi FALSE
>
> |.................................................................| 100%
>
> ordinary text without R code
>
> "PATH1" +RTS -K512m -RTS ECON_404_HW_4.utf8.md --to latex --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers+tex_math_single_backslash --output DOCTITLE.pdf --template "PATH2" --highlight-style tango --latex-engine pdflatex --variable graphics=yes --variable "geometry:margin=1in" 
>   output file: DOCTITLE.knit.md
>
> pandoc.exe: pdflatex not found. pdflatex is needed for pdf output.
>
> Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 41
>
> In addition: Warning message:
>
> running command '"PATH1" +RTS -K512m -RTS DOCTITLE.utf8.md --to latex --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers+tex_math_single_backslash --output DOCTITLE.pdf --template "PATH2" --highlight-style tango --latex-engine pdflatex --variable graphics=yes --variable "geometry:margin=1in"' had status 41
>
> Execution halted
>
> No TeX installation detected (TeX is required to create PDF output). You should install a recommended TeX distribution for your platform:
>
> Windows: MiKTeX (Complete) - http://miktex.org/2.9/setup
>     (NOTE: Be sure to download the Complete rather than Basic installation)
>
> Mac OS X: TexLive 2013 (Full) - http://tug.org/mactex/
>     (NOTE: Download with Safari rather than Chrome *strongly* recommended)
>
> Linux: Use system package manager

I edited out the path locations on my PC as well as the intended title of the PDF (changing them with "PATH1", "PATH2", and "DOCTITLE" where appropriate.)

I have used the link to download MikTex multiple times to multiple locations, I have tried using ProTex as some others have had success doing. I have tried adding the bin of MikTex to the environment but no matter what, it seems that R is unable to find Tex. Most of the advice available is for OSX, and I have tried adapting those solutions for windows to no avail.

Comment: Please open `cmd.exe` and type `pdflatex`. Do you see `This is pdfTeX ...` or an error message?

Comment: Did you install MikTex, completed version? 32bits: http://mirrors.ctan.org/systems/win32/miktex/setup/setup-2.9.5870.exe  64bits: http://mirrors.ctan.org/systems/win32/miktex/setup/setup-2.9.5870-x64.exe  then restart R-studio

Comment: CL, when I type pdflatex I get the response: `This is pdfTex, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 <MiKTeX 2.9>`

Comment: @MattyR did you ever figure this out. having the same problem

Answer (score 0):

@Matty R, after getting that error I  restarted Rstudio, and then it asked me to instally packages like "upquote" using MikTex Package Manager, after three or four packages installation I got the pdf file created.